# Clearing Contents of a Variable Row

Tags: excel, vba

So I am new to this language and am trying to get my head around it. This piece of code is for work and the section here was hugely assisted by an amazing person on this website.

This piece should copy over a row of information to a different spreadsheet when the box in the I Column turns to 7. And thanks to that person it works pretty perfectly.

The next question on my mind though is how to the delete the original row in the first spreadsheet.

I can't use a range like "A9:M9" as the row will not always been in that fixed place.

I tried using:
    `If Source.Column = 9 And Source.Value = "7 - engaged" Then

    Range("A:M").Select
    Selection.ClearContents`

But this wiped the entire worksheet. 
Is there any way to just delete the one row that's been copied?

`If Source.Column <> 9 Then Exit Sub
    If Source.Value <> "7 - engaged" Then Exit Sub`

```
 If MsgBox("Client status selected as engaged. Confirm to post to tank.", 
 vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tank")
        Dim rowToPasteTo As Long
        rowToPasteTo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        .Range("A" & rowToPasteTo & ":" & "D" & rowToPasteTo).Value = 
Sh.Range("A" & Source.Row & ":" & "M" & Source.Row).Value
        .Range("G" & rowToPasteTo & ":" & "H" & rowToPasteTo).Value = 
Sh.Range("E" & Source.Row & ":" & "F" & Source.Row).Value
        .Range("S" & rowToPasteTo & ":" & "U" & rowToPasteTo).Value = 
Sh.Range("K" & Source.Row & ":" & "M" & Source.Row).Value

    End With

 End If

 If Source.Column = 9 And Source.Value = "7 - engaged" Then`
```

Comment: `Source.EntireRow.ClearContents` ?

Comment: Not clear if you want to delete the row or clear the row? because your code clears the row and your question suggests that you want to clear the row. Also, might be worth reading why not to use `Select` and `Activate` in VBA

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look into these! It was one of the first things I learnt (as I usually use Python and work just gave me a task to do on VBA so I figured it out in the sense of completing the task without researching the language at all due to time pressures.) I am definitely interested in learning more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you want to delete the entire row or clear the cells contents:

```
If Source.Column = 9 And Source.Value = "7 - engaged" Then
    ' Option 1 - deletes the entire row
    Source.EntireRow.Delete       

    ' Option 2 - clears the contents  
    Source.EntireRow.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't this `Delete` the `Source` row and then `clear the contents` of the row that replaces the `Source` row?

Comment: @Zac it was meant as to select which of the option the PO wants to use